# how to create a plugin for internet explorer8 or above?

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer

i am asking the same question that many have posted here, but i have gone through almost all the posts and didn't get what am looking for.
my question is how can i create a plugin for IE that creates a tool bar with a button and when user clicks the button, a small popup window comes where he can sign in to our website.
as i am new in the concept, have some doubts..is plugins developed as windows application?

i have tried the sample codes from many sites but getting errors when building the solution. can anyone explain in detail how to get my job done?can we do it using c# in .net?